# Stored procedure did not perform deletion as Intended

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure to delete data, but it is not being executed in one go. It does not perform the delete for me. But the logic for delete operation seems to be correct.

When I click the execute button, it said "Command completed successfully", but when I checked the rows, they have not been deleted, even though there are some older rows.

I tried adding an `IF EXISTS` clause to drop the stored procedure if it exist and it works but the code just did not enter the part where deletion should be performed.

My code:

```
USE SkillTracking;
GO

IF object_id('spDataDeletion') IS NULL
    EXEC ('create procedure dbo.spDataDeletion as select 1')
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE spDataDeletion
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Create a temporary table to store the latest records for each employee for subquery
    -- must figure out null if get deleted by dateadd-- 
    CREATE TABLE #LatestEmployeeRecords 
    (
        LogID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        HIST_EMP_IFXID varchar(10),
        HIST_AS_CURR_SESS NVARCHAR(100),
        RECORDS_DELETED INT,
        HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE DATE,
        DELETION_DATE DATE,
        TIMESTAMP DATETIME
    );

    DECLARE @DELETION_DATE DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
    DECLARE @TIMESTAMP DATETIME;
    SELECT @TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

    -- Insert records into the #LatestEmployeeRecords table
    INSERT INTO #LatestEmployeeRecords (HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, RECORDS_DELETED, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE, DELETION_DATE, TIMESTAMP)
        SELECT 
            HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, RECORDS_DELETED, 
            HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE, @DELETION_DATE, @TIMESTAMP
        FROM  
            (SELECT 
                 HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, 
                 COUNT(*) AS RECORDS_DELETED, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE
             FROM  
                 [dbo].[tblHistoryBackup] 
             WHERE 
                 HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE < DATEADD(MONTH, -36, @DELETION_DATE)
             GROUP BY 
                 HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE) t;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #LatestEmployeeRecords) = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(4000) = 'All records are up to date.'
        --DECLARE @TimeStamp DATETIME;--
        --SET @TimeStamp = GETDATE();--
            
        -- Insert the error message into the logging table
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblLog] (TimeStamp, EventType, Details, IsError)
        VALUES (@TIMESTAMP, 'No record to be deleted', @Message, 0);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @RECORDS_DELETED INT;

        SELECT @RECORDS_DELETED =  SUM(RECORDS_DELETED) 
        FROM #LatestEmployeeRecords

        DECLARE @Message2 NVARCHAR(4000) =  'Succeeded. Total no of records deleted from tblHistory ' + CAST(@RECORDS_DELETED AS NVARCHAR(10));
        --DECLARE @TimeStamp2 DATETIME;--
        --SET @TimeStamp2 = GETDATE();--
         
        -- Insert the error message into the logging table
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblLog] (TimeStamp, EventType, Details, IsError)
        VALUES (@TIMESTAMP, 'Delete successful', @Message2, 0);
    END

    DECLARE @DELETION_DATE2 DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
    -- DELETE FROM TBLHISTORYBACKUP -- 
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblHistoryBackup]
    WHERE HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE < DATEADD(MONTH, -36, @DELETION_DATE2)

    -- INSERT DELETED RECORDS INTO TBLLOGDATADELETION FROM TEMP TABLE--
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblLog_Data_Deletion](LogID, HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, RECORDS_DELETED, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE, DELETION_DATE, TimeStamp)
        SELECT 
            LogID, HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, RECORDS_DELETED, 
            HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE, DELETION_DATE, TIMESTAMP
        FROM 
            #LatestEmployeeRecords;

    --DROP TEMP TABLE--
    DROP TABLE #LatestEmployeeRecords;
END
```

Comment: Debug it, take the SQL out of the SP, pop it in a query window, and run it section by section and check the results... i.e. change deletes to selects to see what records are being filtered etc.

Comment: Its pretty difficult for anyone here to do that for you without access to a table with sample data etc.

Comment: From what I could see, the part above the delete does not edit data in `tblHistoryBackup` so you can quickly check the deletion condition on your table. e.g. `SELECT count(*) as recordsToRemove FROM [dbo].[tblHistoryBackup]
    WHERE HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE < DATEADD(month, -36, GETDATE())` how many records are prior 36 months / 3 years. If this is 0 then there is something wrong with your WHERE statement.

Comment: Please provide some sample data of records that are not deleted, which you claim should be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what your issue is, but you are overcomplicating this.

You can use `OUTPUT` to just retrieve the actual deleted rows directly into a table variable.

Then you can check how many rows were deleted using `@@ROWCOUNT`, and based on that you can do further inserts to logging tables.

You should also begin and commit a transaction to ensure the whole thing happens atomically.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE spDataDeletion
AS 

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE
    @DELETION_DATE DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),
    @TIMESTAMP DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

DECLARE @output TABLE (
  HIST_EMP_IFXID varchar(10),
  HIST_AS_CURR_SESS NVARCHAR(100),
  HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE DATE,
  -- make this index in the same order as the dbo.tblHistoryBackup table's index
  INDEX IX CLUSTERED (HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE)
);

BEGIN TRAN;


DELETE FROM dbo.tblHistoryBackup

OUTPUT deleted.HIST_EMP_IFXID, deleted.HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, deleted.HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE
INTO @output (HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE)

WHERE HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE < DATEADD(MONTH, -36, @DELETION_DATE);

DECLARE @RECORDS_DELETED bigint = @@ROWCOUNT;


IF @RECORDS_DELETED = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(4000) = 'All records are up to date.';
            
    -- Insert the error message into the logging table
    INSERT INTO dbo.tblLog (TimeStamp, EventType, Details, IsError)
    VALUES (@TIMESTAMP,'No record to be deleted', @Message, 0);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Message2 NVARCHAR(4000) = CONCAT('Succeeded. Total no of records deleted from tblHistory ', @RECORDS_DELETED);

    -- Insert the error message into the logging table
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblLog] (TimeStamp, EventType, Details, IsError)
    VALUES (@TIMESTAMP,'Deletion Successful', @Message2, 0);

    -- INSERT DELETED RECORDS INTO TBLLOGDATADELETION FROM TEMP TABLE--
    INSERT INTO dbo.tblLog_Data_Deletion (
      LogID, HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, RECORDS_DELETED,
      HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE, DELETION_DATE, TimeStamp)
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
      HIST_EMP_IFXID,
      HIST_AS_CURR_SESS,
      COUNT(*),
      HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE,
      @DELETION_DATE,
      @TIMESTAMP
    FROM @output u
    GROUP BY
      HIST_EMP_IFXID,
      HIST_AS_CURR_SESS,
      HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE;

END;

COMMIT;
```